# Xcode - how to use a delegate method to hide-unhide buttons

Tags: delegates, uibutton, hidden, xcode4.6

I would Like to know how to use a delegate method to change a button from hidden to unhidden. I haven't used app delegates before and they look really confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok you have **VC1 -> VC2**

you have to make a button `buttonTohide` in VC1 hide from an action`(someAction)` in VC2

1.Add the delegate protocol definition in the header

```
   @protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>
    -(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value;
    @end
```

2.**in VC1.h** make VC1 as a delegate reciever

```
@interface VC1<CustomDelegate>
```

3.**in VC1.m**
implement the method to execute buttonhide

```
-(void)hideUnhidebutton:(BOOL)value
{
[self.buttonTohide setHidden:value];

}
```

4.**in VC2**
add delegate variable as property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<CustomDelegate> delegatePpty;
```

**in VC2.m** at someaction you have to hide button in VC1 so call the delegate method

```
-(void)someAction
{
    [self.delegatePpty hideUnhidebutton:YES];//Call the delegate method to execute
}
```

and it will hide the button for you.Happy coding :)

Comment: i an probably being stubid but for some reason I'm getting a bad receiver type void error can you help ???